# Find $\nabla\cdot (\frac{x}{|x|})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I saw this in an analysis book and was curious how to calculate such a function. My thought is the following:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)&=& \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_i\left(\frac{x_i}{|x|}\right)\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n|x|^{-1}+x_i\left(-\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\right)\\
&=&\frac{n}{|x|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\\
&=&\frac{n-1}{|x|}.
\end{eqnarray*}

My question is when looking at the divergence in the first equality, does the denominator see the index? That is, should it look like "$\frac{x_i}{|x_i|}$"? This is a trivial question but I haven't worked with this is quite some time. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Everything is right. The $i$ th component is $x_i /|x|$.

Comment: Great. Is this because we regard $|x|$ as a scalar function?

Comment: it is scalar valued.

Comment: You could think that $|x|$ involves another, already contracted index ($|x|=\sqrt{x_j x_j}$).